# ASP.NET MVC3 How to use roles to hide delete links from non-admin users?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, roles

I have an mvc3 web application with entity framework 4.1. I've created two roles - users and administrators. When I log into my application as an administrator, I want to see the Delete links next to records in the table. However, if a user logs in, I only want them to see Edit and Details and not Delete.
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I've only ever used the nasty manual @if check.. would like a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mixed bag with multiple answers.  There are two great ways to do it.

One is to create all the links in a controller (or Global Application_Request) based on the logged in user and pass it to the view.  I'm not a fan of this because links being created by the controller are in my opinion, the responsibility of the view.

The second way is to manually check in the view itself.  It's simple it's clean but it is logic in a view.

**Partial-Menu.cshtml**

```
<a href="/User/Attack">Boot To The Head</a>
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
  <a href="/Admin/BootToTheHead">You Missed</a>
}
```

Comment: You can do this in controller by setting ViewData["HideLink"] = !User.IsInRole("Administrator");

Comment: Yes, that would be the same as my first answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Erik. I was aware of this method but thought there was a better way to avoid adding code to the view. At any rate, it works so I'm marking this as the correct answer.